# Python deletion from env variable - with a twist

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, environment-variables

I'm using Windows 7, on a work pc, and trying to complete an uninstall of Python27.

If I open `cmd` and type `path` then I can see the list of env variables which contains `;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;`

If I click to the following `Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.. > Pth` then the Value I see does not contain `;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;`

Why am I seeing this inconsistency? Is one the path for all users and the other just for me?

How do delete `;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;` from all views of path? How do delete that section of path using PS? (without deleting it all!)

Comment: Did you restart the machine after uninstall?

Comment: @Martin a couple of times; I even used regedit and deleted the entry for C:/Python27. Is there an elegant way of editing this `path` string using powershell where the aim is to delete a section in the middle of the string ie delete this bit `;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;`

Comment: @Martin maybe one is machine level path and the other user level? Can there be 2 different values for the Path env variable?

Comment: Yes, the PATH environment variable is an overlay of 2 settings: User and System path. Did you check both of them? In PowerShell try `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path', 'user')` and `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path', 'machine')`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - ok that is the mystery solved - it is the machine level I need to amend - can I do this manually via Computer > Properties? Or am I only going to be able to amend it via cmd or PS? If only via cmd or PS what is the safest approach? Something like this `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable
     ( "Path", $env:Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine )` but I need to delete a section from the middle of  `$env:Path`

Comment: ok it seems like in the machine variable the bit I'd like to delete `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\` is located at the very end of the string  - maybe this makes it easier for me to script a safe way of deleting that section of the string?

Comment: You can do a split with Terminator ; then select all substrings without "Python27", rejoin it using ; and set path variable with result. Or you take a regex for that.

Comment: @Martin would you be able to detail that in an answer: this bit as I'm not conversant with PS `You can do a split with Terminator ; then select all substrings without "Python27"`

Comment: @whytheq See Ansgars answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the two Python folders are listed in the PATH setting of your SYSTEM environment. Either edit that setting as an administrator, or run the following with admin privileges:

```
$python_paths = 'C:\Python27\', 'C:\Python27\Scripts\'

$mpath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine') -split ';' |
         Where-Object { $paths -notcontains $_ }

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ($mpath -join ';'), 'Machine')
```

To remove any Python 2.7 path change the `Where-Object` filter to a wildcard match:

```
... | Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'C:\Python27*' }
```

Comment: I would simply take this approach: `... | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'Python27' }` and I was wondering how the regex variant would look like.

Comment: Umm... that *is* the regex variant. However, it's a little too unspecific for my taste, since it would match the string `python27` anywhere in the path.

Comment: "with admin privileges" ...I can add a temporary setting, via a PS script, to give myself these privileges ?

Comment: I must have the required priviliges as it seems to be working ok

Comment: You can re-run the script in "runas" mode, so that it is run elevated (if you are a member of the administrators group) or prompts for credentials (if you aren't), or you can run code (scripts, scriptblocks, ...) with explicit credentials. That's a different question, though. One that has been answered several times already.

Comment: ok - I logged into PS "As Admin" and it ran ok. Python has gone from the variable.